# Send request from windows phone 7 to server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am a beginner in WP7. I need to send a request to the server. The request included username,  password and an authentication header. If succeeded I get some data from the server in xml form. How can I send the request to the server?

Comment: Request what? Do you need to call an webservice? Http url? What have you tried till now?

Comment: @Nelson T Joseph Have you find this Solution???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly shouldn't be using the `WebClient` class as this executes on the UI thread so will cause the app to lock, instead look at the `HttpWebRequest` class.

There is a good example here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156610/WP7-WebClient-vs-HttpWebRequest

To add headers, you can access the `HttpWebRequest.Headers` property so you could add a basic authorization header as per this http://devproj20.blogspot.com/2008/02/assigning-basic-authorization-http.html
Alternatively, you can use the HttpWebRequest.Credentials property (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx for more details)

You'd want to check the status code of the response to verify if the authentication was successful, so you'd access the `HttpWebResponse.StatusCode` property and see if if it is 401 (unauthorized).

Comment: With Mango update there is no difference between WebClient and HttpWebRequest - both executed in thread from which they have been called.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    string xml = e.Result;
};
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://..." + your params));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void SendRequest()
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://somesite.com/webservice"));
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted +=DownloadStringCompleted;
}

void DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Web service says: " + e.Result);
}
```

Comment: If you're a beginner in WP7 (like the asker), don't (whatever you do) use WebClient as the answer suggests, see http://forums.silverlight.net/t/216188.aspx/1 for details

Comment: In Mango WebClient and HttpWebRequest both executed in thread from which they have been called. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/21/webclient-change-for-mango-how-it-impacts-your-application.aspx

Comment: I'm not a beginner in WP7. But almost all my experience is in XNA and game dev, and I didn't notice such problems there. Thanks a lot, I'm going to make some extra testing in my projects.